# jQuery event to find elements with the same class of $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have lets say 10 div elements. In these 10 divs, I have 5 divs with a certain class and then duplicated it for 5 also (so it counts as 10),

If I trigger event on a certain class, then how can the code be applied also to the duplicated class?

```js
$('div').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css("background","red");
}).mouseout(function(){
     $(this).css("background","none");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="text">I can tell that I am being hovered, but I want my identical twin to apply code from it also</div>
    <div class="text">I can tell that I am being hovered, but I want my identical twin to apply code from it also</div>
    <div class="text2">I can tell that I am being hovered, but I want my identical twin to apply code from it also</div>
    <div class="text2">I can tell that I am being hovered, but I want my identical twin to apply code from it also</div>
    <div class="text3">I can tell that I am being hovered, but I want my identical twin to apply code from it also</div>
    <div class="text3">I can tell that I am being hovered, but I want my identical twin to apply code from it also</div>
    <div class="text4">I can tell that I am being hovered, but I want my identical twin to apply code from it also</div>
    <div class="text4">I can tell that I am being hovered, but I want my identical twin to apply code from it also</div>
```

Comment: Always post your code in your question. You saw the warning about this when you linked to jsFiddle and decided to sidestep the warning by highlighting a link as code.

Comment: I'm unsure of what the problem is. Could you elaborate further?

Comment: Sorry I am new to stackoverflow, i think Nicholas Young got what I needed.

Comment: @NormanSilvestre Edited your post to include a live demo in the question.

Comment: Thank You @Vega! and all you guys for the support :)

Answer (score 2):

Get the current Elements className and apply style to all the elements. See demo below,

**Solution 1:** (Lenient match meaning elements containing matching className)

```js
$('div').mouseover(function() {
  var className = this.className.split(' ');
  $('.' + className.join('.')).css("background", "red");
}).mouseout(function() {
  var className = this.className.split(' ');
  $('.' + className.join('.')).css("background", "none");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">I can tell that I am being hovered, but I want my identical twin to apply code from it also</div>
<div class="text">I can tell that I am being hovered, but I want my identical twin to apply code from it also</div>
<div class="text2">I can tell that I am being hovered, but I want my identical twin to apply code from it also</div>
<div class="text2">I can tell that I am being hovered, but I want my identical twin to apply code from it also</div>
<div class="text3">I can tell that I am being hovered, but I want my identical twin to apply code from it also</div>
<div class="text3">I can tell that I am being hovered, but I want my identical twin to apply code from it also</div>
<div class="text4">I can tell that I am being hovered, but I want my identical twin to apply code from it also</div>
<div class="text4">I can tell that I am being hovered, but I want my identical twin to apply code from it also</div>
```

**Solution 2:** **Strict Match** (requires exact className match when having multiple classes)

```js
$('div').mouseover(function () {
    var _this = this;
    var className = this.className.split(' ');
    $('.' + className.join('.')).filter(function () {
        return this.className === _this.className;
    }).css("background", "red");
}).mouseout(function () {
    var _this = this;
    var className = this.className.split(' ');
    $('.' + className.join('.')).filter(function () {
        return this.className === _this.className;
    }).css("background", "none");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text4 text2">I can tell that I am being hovered, but I want some elements with same class as me to apply the code also.</div>
<div class="text4">I can tell that I am being hovered, but I want some elements with same class as me to apply the code also.</div>
<div class="text4 text2">I can tell that I am being hovered, but I want some elements with same class as me to apply the code also.</div>
<div class="text4">I can tell that I am being hovered, but I want some elements with same class as me to apply the code also.</div>
```

Comment: @NormanSilvestre Just in case if you wanted a **strict** match **http://jsfiddle.net/fhhjaL3n/7/** (meaning the class name should exactly match)

Comment: @NormanSilvestre I somehow knew you would need that, anyways.. don't forget to accept the best answer that worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/fhhjaL3n/2/

```
$('div').mouseover(function(){
    $("."+$(this)[0].classList[0]).css("background","red");
}).mouseout(function(){
   $("."+$(this)[0].classList[0]).css("background","none");
});
```

NOTE, this will NOT work if you add more classes to the div. It will work with your current code, so experiment with this.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas Young your code is useful to me I will experiment with this!

Answer (score 0):

Only works if the className is exactly the same, of course:

```
$(getElementsyByClassName(this.className);
```

Avoiding slow jQuery selectors at all costs.

You can even avoid jQuery completely (which is cool):

```
var matchedEl = document.getElementsByClassName(this.className);
for (var i = 0, count = matchedEl.length; i < count; i++) {
    matchedEl[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

Thanx to Vega for pointing it out, always nice to live without jQuery :)

Comment: Avoiding jQuery means `document.getElementsByClassName(this.className)` and then iterating over each Elements to set the style, your answer is still using jQuery functions.

Comment: just realized it, thanx. although, i did not say "avoid jquery", i said "avoid slow jquery selectors" ;) - it's edited.

Comment: Ah I see, my bad.. anyways worked on a demo using your answer.. http://jsfiddle.net/fhhjaL3n/6/

Comment: Nice!! Im glad that you guys are out there to help us find a way how to solve issues, I am a beginner in this field so I am not used to create such nice and fast code! Thank you @luschn !

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do it:
you shouldn't manipulate css with jquery. because jquery automatically set css with style attr and it has a specificity of 1000.
http://jsbin.com/hawenadefo/2/edit?html,css,js,output